# Powershell Invoke method neither throwing exception nor returning result

Tags: powershell, automation

I am trying to build an ASP.Net, c# application to expose few IIS management related activities through web interface for a distributed Admin group.

I am making use of System.Management.Automation V3.0 library to wrap power shell commands. As a first step I wanted to list all Web Applications that are currently up and running on local IIS by invoking  Get-WebApplication command.
This is where I am facing the issue. Method call is neither throwing any exception nor its returning the result. Does anyone know the root cause of this issue? Please share your experience of building such interface using System.Management.Automation.dll.

```
 var shell = PowerShell.Create();              
          shell.Commands.AddScript("Get-WebApplication | Out-String");
          try
          {
              var results = shell.Invoke();
              if (results.Count > 0)
              {
                  var builder = new StringBuilder();
                  foreach (var psObject in results)
                  {                          
                      builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                  }
              }

          }                  
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              throw;
          }
```

PS: Get-Service in place of Get-WebApplication works absolutely fine by returning list of services available on the machine.

Comment: Empty result can be valid result. So, do you have any web application on local server? And did your check content of `shell.Streams.Error`?

Comment: Yes, there are few applications on local server. Thanks for pointing to Streams.Error property. I found the following exception message **Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).**

Comment: Does this cmdlet work in PowerShell console? x32 **and** x64?

Comment: Its working fine in x64 but giving error message in x32. Error message is same as what I received in the code.

Comment: And your application is x32?

Comment: I haven't altered the default value of **platform target** i.e **Any CPU** but I received following exception when I tried to set platform target as x64  **System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'INetWebMgr' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. **

Comment: `INetWebMgr` is your assembly name? I does not have experience with ASP.Net and does not know how exactly bitness determined here. Possible, you just have to match bitness of worker process. Maybe, creating out of process `Runspace` with x64 PowerShell will be simplest solution.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, INetWebMgr is the name of my web application. As mentioned in my question, I am trying to build web interface by wrapping power shell commands. I am not sure at this moment whether I can create out of process Runspace and still provide web interface on top of it. I would like to now if there is any way I can force Powershell.Create() method to start 64 bit PS process instead of 32 bit process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PowerShell.Create()` does not create new PowerShell process. If you does not specify `Runspace` for it, then it will create new in-process `Runspace`. Since it run in your process, it will match your process bitness and you can not change that. To create `Runspace` with different bitness you need to create out of process `Runspace`. Here is a sample console application, which demonstrate how you can do that:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
public static class TestApplication {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess);
        using(PowerShellProcessInstance pspi = new PowerShellProcessInstance()) {
            string psfn = pspi.Process.StartInfo.FileName;
            psfn=psfn.ToLowerInvariant().Replace("\\syswow64\\", "\\sysnative\\");
            pspi.Process.StartInfo.FileName=psfn;
            using(Runspace r = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null, pspi)) {
                r.Open();
                using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
                    ps.Runspace=r;
                    ps.AddScript("[Environment]::Is64BitProcess");
                    foreach(PSObject pso in ps.Invoke()) {
                        Console.WriteLine(pso);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you compile this application as x32, it still will use x64 out of process `Runspace` on x64 operation system.