# System.Management.Automation.PowerShell does not return results for Get-Website from IIS

Tags: c#, powershell, iis

We're using `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` for executing PowerShell scripts.

Everything worked fine for many scenarios until we need to set some properties of a web site on IIS (ServerAutostart etc.).

We made a PS1 script which works as we expected, however, after execution via C#, it crashes. After some exploration, I extracted the problematic part:

PS1 script:

```
# Set execution policy
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force

# Import modules
Import-Module WebAdministration
Import-Module IISAdministration -MinimumVersion 1.1.0.0

# Getting IIS Sites
$iisSite = Get-IISSite

If ($iisSite)
{
    Write-Host "$($iisSite.Count) IISSites were found"
} 
else 
{
    Write-Error "IISSite was not found"
}

$webSite = Get-Website

# Getting Web Sites

If ($webSite)
{
    Write-Host "$($webSite.Count) WebSites were found"
} 
else 
{
    Write-Error "WebSites was not found"
}
```

If I run it via `Windows PowerShell ISE`, it works perfectly:

```
23 IISSites were found
23 WebSites were found
```

However, if the script is executed via C# and `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`, it returns following:

```
23 IISSites were found
WebSites was not found
```

What is the difference? Why `Get-IISSite` works and `Get-Website` not? Permissions? Missing modules?

To set WebSite properties, we need to work with it via `Get-WebSite`. Unfortunately, it seems to be a conceptual problem...

Thank you for your help...

Comment: do you run your C# app "as administrator"?

Comment: Yes, that was one the first things I tried. No effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by **prefering 32-bit mode** in the **Build** tab in 64-bit system.

[Prefering 32-bit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPDsK.png)

After uncheck, everything works well.

see [Powershell Invoke method neither throwing exception nor returning result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875985/powershell-invoke-method-neither-throwing-exception-nor-returning-result)