# Run PowerShell as 32-bit or 64-bit from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I build a 32-bit .NET DLL that executes PowerShell scripts.
I need it to be able to run scripts alternatively as 64-bit **and** 32-bit.

I already know how to do it with the command line:

```
C:\Windows\Sysnative\cmd /c powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'script.ps1' arguments"
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd /c powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'script.ps1' arguments"
```

But I need to be able to use the interface to C#, with either the `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` class or the `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline` class, in order to asynchronously collect outputs from the script.

Comment: You will need to build your c# app to target x86 or amd64 exclusively and then just use the classes.  You don't have the ability to pick at run time like you can from the console.

Comment: You explicitly cannot use 64-bit libraries in a 32-bit application.

Comment: You can use out of process runspace to run PowerShell in different bitness than your process. You can see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919564).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment from @PetSerAl is the solution. With an out of process runspace, I can change the bitness.

I copy his code here:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
public static class TestApplication {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess);
        using(PowerShellProcessInstance pspi = new PowerShellProcessInstance()) {
            string psfn = pspi.Process.StartInfo.FileName;
            psfn=psfn.ToLowerInvariant().Replace("\\syswow64\\", "\\sysnative\\");
            pspi.Process.StartInfo.FileName=psfn;
            using(Runspace r = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null, pspi)) {
                r.Open();
                using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
                    ps.Runspace=r;
                    ps.AddScript("[Environment]::Is64BitProcess");
                    foreach(PSObject pso in ps.Invoke()) {
                        Console.WriteLine(pso);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fix.. it worked for my project.. i was struggling from 8 hrs to make my project work. I was almost about to give up and your code saved my project. thank you