# Run Powershell Script in c# using Powershell Class

Tags: c#, powershell, invoke, execute

I know this question is getting asked a lot. But none of the Solutions helped me.

My Script won't run.
When I'm executing it with Powershell it works.
But not with this C# Code :

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript(@"& 'MyPathToTheScript'");
    ps.Invoke();
}
```

As you can see I tried AddScript and AddCommand, but either won't run my script.
I followed the Instructions that I saw on Microsoft Docs :

[Adding and invoking commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.1)

Except i don't need any parameters :)

**Edit#1**

My PowerShell Script, needs to be run as Administrator. Could this be the issue ? That the script runs, but throws an Error 'cause of 'Access denied'?

Can I do this from C# or do I have to add this in the script ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you have permission issues, it might be useful to test with a very simple script, so that you are only testing the c# - powershell integration.

Comment: I found the solution, it was becaus the Powershell didnt run in 64 bit. Now it works. I'll post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my Solution in this thread. The Script was executed in behind, but didn't found the New-LocalUser function, so I googled and found out, that the Powershell has to run in 64 bit.  I added the Code from the link below to my C# Code and it worked :)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744041/14353101)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the SDK but as stated in [the documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), it seems that methods including `AddScript` create a command pipeline, and `Invoke` should be called on them.

So maybe you should use it like below:

```cs
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create().AddScript("YourPathToTheScript"))
{
    ps.Invoke();
}
```